# Text Selection: Change in double-click behavior

Tags: macos, text-editing

When double-clicking the beginning of an email like foo@example.com, I could easily get the local-part (i.e. 'foo').  However, now when I double-click it also includes the domain (i.e. 'foo@example').

Is there a way to change this behavior to only get the local-part?

This is in Chrome (latest stable) on macOS 13.2.1.

Comment: Where? System? Application? My crystal ball is dysfunctionning.

Comment: Apologies.  Just added.  Your question alone was helpful in that I thought it was system-wide, but the desired behavior happens in Textpad

Comment: No problem Bill, you should Edit your question and put Textpad there. I'm not familiar with Mac, sorry.

Comment: @BillReardon: does this answer your question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/124788/2181?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome & a fix is being rolled out.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1410331